# connecction of remote debbuging disconnect after few seconds when debbug java applet in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, applet

I am trying to debug client side applet with intellij, I have configured remote debugging in the IDE for local host and added the parameters in java console, now when I start the applet from local browser I can connect with the debugger, and even it stop in a breakpoint, but after few seconds (even if I do nothing),I get a message in the IDE console that the connection was disconnected and I can't connect again until I close and open the applet. 
what can I do to make this work properly?

Answer (score 0):

i have succeeded , i put those parameters in java console, (not the ones intellij give)

-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=2502,server=y,suspend=n

and open the browser as administrator, and can debug perfectly

Comment: Are you the same person who originally asked the question? Or is it just a strange coincidence that your username is the same :P Just wondering why you wouldn't just answer your own question if that were the case.